# $p$-adic and mod $p$ relation on tensor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $G$ an abelian group. $\Bbb Z_{p} $
is the $p$-adic integers.

What can one say about
$\Bbb Z/p \otimes G$ given that $\Bbb Z_{p} \otimes G \not= 0$?

Is it possible to conclude whether the former is zero or nonzero?

Comment: What does that say? that is not what i meant by $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$. I edited.

Comment: Ok, my previous comment is not a counterexample then. Under your hypothesis, $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes G$ can be both zero and non zero. For non zero, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$. For zero, consider $G=\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: A notational complaint: $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is most often used to denote the localization of the integers at the ideal $(p)$, which is decidedly *not* the $p$-adics, which are usually just denoted $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: @KReiser Agreed, this was my confusion in my first, now deleted, comment.

Comment: What is each tensor product meant to be over: $\mathbf Z$? $\mathbf Z/(p)$ for the first and $\mathbf Z_p$ for the second? Please edit to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

By right exactness of the tensor product, we have the following exact sequence of abelian groups:

$G\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{p}\xrightarrow{\times p} G\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{p}\rightarrow G\otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\rightarrow 0$.

So letting $M$ be the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ module $G\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, we know that $M$ is nonzero, and we would like to know whether $pM$ is a proper submodule of $M$. If $M$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then we may use Nakayamas lemma to conclude that $pM$ is proper in $M$, since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is local with maximal ideal generated by $p$.

However, if $M$ is not finitely generated, then the multiplication by $p$ map may be surjective, giving $M/pM=G\otimes \mathbb{Z}/p=0$. An example where this holds is letting $G$ be the rational numbers under addition. We just need to check that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is nonzero, which holds since we may tensor further up to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to obtain something nonzero.

To conclude, $G\otimes \mathbb{Z}/p$ could be zero even if $G\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is nonzero, but if $G\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $G\otimes \mathbb{Z}/p$ will be nonzero.